# DOS Batch File Variable Modifier Returns Blank

Tags: variables, datetime, batch-file, dos, modifiers

I have a DOS batch file that will create a report listing files contained within a folder tree.  The code below produces the desired output for over 115,000 files. However, 13 records are produced with blank date/time and file size. When I manually execute the DIR command (without the /b option), the desired file information is presented. Can this be corrected without adding considerable workaround code?

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR "<Path>" /a:-d /b /s') DO (
  ECHO %%~tA %%~zA %%~dpA %%~nA %%~xA >> test.txt
)
```

Comment: Anything common about these 13 files? We can't really help without any insight into this.

Comment: Add `%%~fA` to your `echo` subcommand (not solving but should show at least full-pathed file names) and [take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28208711/3439404)

Answer (score 1):

```
(FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR "<Path>" /a:-d /b /s') DO (
  if exists "%%~A" ECHO %%~tA %%~zA %%~dpA %%~nA %%~xA 
)) >> test.txt
```

The main reason for not obtaining a date/filesize is that the file can not be found.

How does your code work?

The `for /f` starts a separate `cmd` instance that runs the `dir` command.

When all the data has been retrieved and loaded into memory (that is, the `cmd`/`dir` command finished), then the `for` will start to iterate over the retrieved lines. Some time have passed between the information retrieval and the information processing.

In this time, "maybe" the problematic files have been moved/deleted/renamed and they can no be accessed to retrieve their properties. So, first check if the file still exists

The aditional parenthesis and redirection change are to avoid having to open the target file for each `echo` operation. This way, the file is opened at the start of the `for` command and closed at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the code optimization comments. Unfortunately, I can find no pattern to the files (e.g. special characters in file name, old files, etc.). The problematic files are repeatable and do not move or change during execution of the batch file.